# Getting an "Unable to load WSDL" error

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, web-services, air, wsdl

I'm getting this error when I try to load the WSDL for my Asp.Net WebService.

```
faultCode    "Server.Error.Request"   
faultDetail    "Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (http://myurl/web/Service.asmx?WSDL)"   
faultString    "HTTP request error"
```

here is the code:

```
service = new WebService();
service.addEventListener("fault", onServiceFault);
service.addEventListener(LoadEvent.LOAD, onWSDLLoaded);
service.loadWSDL(url);
```

I've done a ton of googling and found several possible solutions but it does not appear to be any of them. I'll go through what I've tried.

1. I can open the link in a browser IE and FF.
2. There's no user signed certificate required
3. My crossdomain is setup correctly

Here's the really interesting part, it works if I compile and run with Flex SDK 3.2 but I was trying to integrate AIR 2.5 for some features that are required and so I updated to Flex 3.5 w/ AIR 2.5 on top. If I build with this SDK it does not work.

I've used an HTTP traffic montior(Fiddler) to looked at the requests and noticed that with the 3.5 SDK it does not ever send out the request. So it must be something in the flex side, because it's obviously never getting to my service.

Does anyone have any other suggestions on what to try or is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the exact same problem with Flex 4.0/AIR 2.5 when the .air is installed on a Windows OS.  On Mac OS it works perfectly fine.  When running/debugging from code, it works perfectly fine.  The code is set up to do a .loadWSDL() on a webservice that is behind a valid SSL certificate.

Downgrading to AIR 2.0 fixes it.

Any suggestions here would be great.  Thanks to the original poster for articulating this problem.

UPDATE:  Turns out it's an AIR 2.5 problem with setting the Flex Framework files to be RSLs.  I have helped Adobe track it down and they have recreated it now:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/3345972#3345972

Comment: Sorry I should have posted this when I figured this out as well. You are correct, I had to downgrade to AIR 2.0 to fix this issue. I'll test again in the future with later updates with AIR but for now stick with 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I've been searching for a similar issue for hours now, Your post to adobe had my answer, deploying on live without dissabling the Flash Builders "Network Monitor" feature causes the same error =]